# Bash: if and typecheck

Tags: bash

Hi guys i am new to this. Hoping that you could help me
I am writing this (should be simple) bash script to check if the filetype is txt or zip. but it does not work

the code is:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "please insert file"
read file
if [ $file == *.txt ]
then
emacs $file
elif [ $file == *.zip ]
then 
zip $file
fi
```

Comment: `sh` is usually not `bash`.

Comment: And even if `sh` *is* `bash`, `[` doesn't do pattern matching.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a case statement.

```
case "$file" in
*.txt) emacs $file ;;
*.zip) zip   $file ;;
esac
```

Comment: thx! solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can either use:

`if [ ${file: -4} == ".txt" ]`
and thus compare the last 4 characters

Or use:

`if [[ $file == *.txt ]]`
and thus use a regular expression (double brackets are available only in some shells but it is available in `bash`).